# tcl: stop proc from continue

Tags: tcl

I wrote a script that need to work inside tool.
When sourcing the file I want "checker" proc will drop the entire sourcing if $current > $exp
The problem is a inner command inside the tool call "exit" and this command cause tool to exit.
How can I implement it?
I tried instead of "exit" use "error" but it print additional errors and don't stop my script clearly.

```
proc checker {} {
    set current 100
    set exp 50
    if {${current} > ${exp}} {
        exit
    }
}

checker 

puts "done!!"
```

Answer (score 3):

A `return` statement in a script will stop sourcing a script.

When you're in the proc, you can use `return -level <integer>` to return not only from the proc, also from a higher level in the call stack.

This is equivalent to using the `uplevel` command to execute a command at higher level in the call stack.

Comment: When using `return -level 2 -code error` it print error twice.
Is is possible to print only once?